# Detect browser Language then Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser, lang

Yo lads! I need some help here, on my website I want to redirect my visitors to a specific page for their language. So far I have this  but it keeps loop the page all the time, doesnt redirect to the page I want.. Does anybody can help me to fix this or do you have a better reliable solution for me? I rly appreciate!! cheers

UPDATE: Loop issue is fixed, but i think something is wrong with the my var userLang == "en", it always redirect to the default.php page and not to the '/en' page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        if (userLang == "en") {
            window.location.href = "/en"
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "default.php"
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this code on `default.php` or something else? Also, it should be `/default.php` and you want to check if the language starts with "en" (mine has "en-US" for instance).

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. Yes, default.php is the main page, where the code is loaded

Comment: So if the `else` triggers, what do you think is going to happen?

Comment: right the loop lol

Comment: I just fix the code it seems to be working now, cheers mate. But still for the user Lang should i use en or en-us, because both seems not to be working on my side.. it always call the default.php

Comment: `navigator.lang.startsWith("en")` should work

Comment: nop. doesnt work either :(